# Angular 13 https

Tags: angular, ssl, angular-cli

I generated a certificate using certbot. And as a result , I received such files:

```
cert.pem
chain.pem
fullchain.pem
privkey.pem
```

How to make angular 13 work over https?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run ng serve with custom certificate:

```
ng serve --ssl --ssl-key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain/privkey.pem --ssl-cert /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain/cert.pem
```

[Documentation](https://angular.io/cli/serve)

EDIT: updated to include your specific files

Comment: `Support for camel case arguments has been deprecated and will be removed in a future major version.
Use '--ssl-key' instead of '--sslKey'.
Unknown option: '-t'
Unknown option: '/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain/fullchain.pem'` I also tried using an `--ssl-key`

Comment: my bad, updated